# How to change the background of this text?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors

I have a DOCX file which I need to adapt.

The document contains a table which currently looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

That grey background is not the correct grey, so I need to change it.

However, that text is neither highlighted nor does it have a background color:
[image: Screenshot]

Also, it's not the background color of the cell (sorry for the German screenshot, it says "no color"). Also, other cells with a background do not have a 2 pixel gap on the left and right side.

[image: Screenshot]

Where does the grey background come from and how do I change it?

The text is real text, not a bitmap or something. The style is "Standard", which is used in many places in the document as well.

Here's how it looks like when I set the highlighting to yellow and the background to blue and special characters visible:

[image: Screenshot]

Please do not suggest to remove the entire table. Of course I could do that, but I'm here to learn something new about Word.

I'm using Word 2016, but the document may be from an older version.

Answer to a comment:

Changing the style of the entire table changes everything except that text:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Very strange.  I can't replicate the problem.  Can you post the docx?

Comment: @dav: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=58138152395605499703

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem looks to be due to Borders and Shading settings (and their many layers).  To clear the formatting try:

1. Select the table paragraph
2. Home > Paragraph > Border and Shading
3. On the Shading Tab, choose Paragraph from the `Apply to` box **and** Choose No Color in the `Fill` box. Then click OK.  (You must choose No Color, even if it already appears selected in the dropdown box).
4. If that doesn't work, then repeat with Text in the `Apply to` box.

[Shauna Kelly](https://shaunakelly.com/word/styles/shading-in-paragraph-styles.html) has a great description of all of these options (and a ton of other Word issues).

Comment: Damn, I got it working. The key thing for me was: I had to click the combobox for the color and choose "no color" again, even if there's already "no color" selected.

Comment: I'm glad it's working.  I added emphasis to that part in my answer also-it's easy to overlook.  You'd think that MS would auto apply it since it's the default selection-or leave the selection blank so you wouldn't assume it's application.